# where is something wrong with my query?

Tags: sql, join

```
with StudentTakes (name, id, course_id) as (
    select name, student.id, course_id
    from takes join student on takes.id = student.id
)
select distinct name, id 
from StudentTakes a
where a.name in (
    select b.name 
    from StudentTakes b
    where b.name = a.name and b.id <> a.id and a.course_id = b.course_id
)
order by name;
```

I want to find the `name` and `ID` of students, each of whom has name that is the same with other students, and the students who have the same name must study in the class that has the same `course_id`. Table `takes` contain `ID` and `course_id`. Table student contains `ID` and `name`. The total number of students who have the same names is **788** and the result of the above query is 755. Can someone explain why when I change the code above as follow, the result is **788**.

```
with StudentTakes (name, id, course_id) as (
    select name, student.id, course_id
    from takes join student on takes.id = student.id
)
select distinct name, id 
from StudentTakes a
where a.name in (
    select b.name 
    from StudentTakes b
    where b.name = a.name and b.id <> a.id and a.course_id <> b.course_id -- CHANGE
)
order by name;
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: The 2nd query is more inclusive because you're not requiring the `course_id` to match, so any two students with the same name will be returned unless they both only had one class.

Comment: @GoatCO, the second query is not more inclusive; it is just different.  It will miss a student returned by the first query if every class that student takes is also taken by all other students with the same name (though that may be unlikely).

Comment: @JohnBollinger It returns more records, therefore it is more inclusive.  You're right about that, it could be multiple courses as long as the students both appear in all of them, from the data this clearly isn't the case, since 788 is the total number of students that have the same name according to OP.

Comment: @GoatCO, depending on the data, the second query can omit records returned by the first query.  If it does not happen to do so for a particular data set then that's a function of the data, not of the queries.  It is in that sense that I claim the second query itself is not "more inclusive" than the first.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your queries are telling you

1. that there are 755 students who take the same class as another student having the same name (first query), and
2. that 788 students who each have the same name as another take at least one class that is not taken by at least one other student having the same name (second query).

These results are not inherently inconsistent.

Comment: I think you've misread the 2nd query, it's the `course_id` that's set to not match, so it's 788 students who have the same name as another student who is in at least one different course.

Comment: @GoatCO you're right, I missed slightly.  Corrected.